# Files listing include subdirectories and sorted tree

Tags: php

I have one main directory "Images" and many subdirectories - inside them are files (in main folder too). Example tree:

```
+Images
-first.jpg
-second.jpg
++FOLDER1
--image1.jpg
++FOLDER2
--image2.jpg
```

I found a script there:

```
function ListFiles($dir) {
    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();
        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
        return $files;
    }
}
$list = ListFiles('../upload/_thumbs/Images');
sort($list);

foreach ($list as $key=>$file){
    echo '<option value="">'.$file.'</option>';
}
```

This script works fine but I can sort my results by folders (first main content, then rest)... I get i my select:

```
../upload/_thumbs/Images/first.jpg
../upload/_thumbs/Images/FOLDER1/image1.jpg
../upload/_thumbs/Images/FOLDER2/image2.jpg
../upload/_thumbs/Images/second.jpg
```

Expection:

```
../upload/_thumbs/Images/first.jpg
../upload/_thumbs/Images/second.jpg
../upload/_thumbs/Images/FOLDER1/image1.jpg
../upload/_thumbs/Images/FOLDER2/image2.jpg
```

I would be glad if you will help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are sorting with the full path. Instead of sort, I would use uasort which is similar to sort, except you use a callback function to define which goes first.

alternatively, you could get by prepending the file name to the path and using the key on insert. In other words:

```
 array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
```

becomes:

```
 $files[$file . $dir] = $dir . "/" . $file;
```

then you sort using ksort

Comment: Everything is OK! Thanks! Should be: 
$files[$dir. $file] = $dir . "/" . $file;
ksort sorts my select high to low - how change it? From low to high?

Answer (score 2):

Well it probably has something to do with the sort function you call somewhere in the last lines

```
sort($list);
```

It's causing the array to sort alphabetical. You could try to leave it out, or you could try to use natsort.

```
 natsort($list);
```